# How to distinguish multilingualism from polyglotism?

Tags: psycholinguistics, multilingualism

What are defining criteria, and how can we decide whether a person speaking, say, ten languages is a multilingual or a polyglot?

Comment: I think your question should define what you mean by 'multilingual' and 'polyglot'. As far as I'm aware, they're the same thing, at least when used to refer to individuals.

Comment: That is the question same to that I have asked.

Comment: So you agree they mean the same thing?

Comment: No, I agree we need a definition for each one of them to understand whether they are synonyms or not.

Comment: If the question is about definitions (even if the words are related to linguistics), might it be better served on [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't think so, for the question is about definitions for two types of language pracices at their psycholinguistic level.

Comment: I (for one) am not convinced they refer to different things, at least when applied to individuals (I accept that societies may be described as 'multilingual' but have not seen one described as 'polyglot').